# Test the real user (as opposed to switchUser) in Spring Security staticRules

Tags: grails, spring-security, impersonation

In my Grails projects I'm using the Switch User feature (restricted to `ROLE_ADMIN` users) to test the app, simulating various users.

I also have a web console that is restricted to admin users:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
    ...
    "/console/**": ["ROLE_ADMIN"],
    "/plugins/console*/**": ["ROLE_ADMIN"],
    ...
]
```

But while I'm simulating another user, my access to the console is revoked.

How can I change those two static rules, so that they test the role (or username) of the real user, as opposed to the one being impersonated?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing what user is being checked for roles you could also add ROLE_ADMIN to the impersonated user.

See this post on how to set up custom roles for impersonated users. http://beckje01.com/blog/2015/04/18/springsecurity-impersonate-users-custom-roles/

Comment: Thanks, but I definitely do _not_ want to add spurious roles to impersonated users, otherwise the tests I perform using them would be useless!